# Cosine angle between vectors formula in R^4 and greater

Tags: vectors

I understand how the formula is derived from the law of cosines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I dont understand what the author is trying to convey when he states that "This makes sense since ...". Can anyone elaborate on why this is significant? TIA

[image]

Comment: With that definition, the dot product of two unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n {\in}\mathbb Z^+$ is always betwwen $-1$ and $1$ inclusive.

Comment: To understand why "the" derivation is of limited validity, we'd need to see it. This would help us know which facts would mean taking $\theta:=\arccos\frac{u\cdot v}{uv}$ "makes sense" in the light of "the derivation", without its being valid more generally.